# Read write and display image using openVX

Tags: openvx

I am trying to read image using openVX.
I have written following program by referring some samples.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
//#include <vx_examples.h>
#include <VX/vx.h>
//#include <VX/vx_helper.h>

using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
 cout << "SampleOpenVXCode" << endl;
 vx_image vxSrc;
 vx_context context = vxCreateContext();
 vxuFReadImage(context, argv[1], vxSrc);
 vxuFWriteImage(context, vxSrc, "/home/deepak/Desktop/test.jpg");
}
```

But I am getting following error.

```
openvxTest.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
openvxTest.cpp:18:39: error: ‘vxuFReadImage’ was not declared in this scope
  vxuFReadImage(context, argv[1], vxSrc);
                                       ^
openvxTest.cpp:20:65: error: ‘vxuFWriteImage’ was not declared in this scope
  vxuFWriteImage(context, vxSrc, "/home/deepak/Desktop/test.jpg");
```

Also I was not able to find the functions `vxuFWriteImage()` and `vxuFReadImage()` in the `openVX` headers (`openvx/include/VX/vx_*` ).

Can anybody help me to read write and display images using openVX.

Thank you.

Comment: `vxuFWriteImage` and `vxuFReadImage` are artifacts of OpenVX sample implementation. They are declared in separate header (`vx_lib_debug.h`).

Comment: are these functioms written specifically for sample program ?. Where I can find the implementation of this ?. I am not able to find `vx_lib_debug.h`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such function in [OpenVX specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenVX/specs/1.1_SC/OpenVX_Specification_SC_1_1.pdf). This is being cross compiled for a specific platform? Because they might have written this API and hence appropriate header file and library needs to be linked.